# Find unique words in a python dataframe column and count them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, counter, frequency

I am trying to find unique no of words and how many times they have repeated.

Trying to write the code in python for the same.

Input dataset:

| Movie | genre |
| --- | --- |
| movie 1 | Action/Animation/Sci-Fi |
| movie 2 | Adventure/Animation/Drama/Mystery/Sci-Fi |

output dataset:

| Genre | count |
| --- | --- |
| Sci-Fi | 2 |
| Animation | 2 |
| Action | 1 |
| Adventure | 1 |
| Drama | 1 |
| Mystery | 1 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`collections.Counter()` is your friend. You can turn the resulting dict into a dataframe with the `DataFrame` constructor.

```
import pandas as pd
import collections

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ["movie 1", "Action/Animation/Sci-Fi"],
        ["movie 2", "Adventure/Animation/Drama/Mystery/Sci-Fi"],
    ],
    columns=["Movie", "Genre"],
)

ctr = collections.Counter()
for r in df["Genre"]:
    ctr.update(r.split("/"))
print(ctr)

# output: Counter({'Animation': 2, 'Sci-Fi': 2, 'Action': 1, 'Adventure': 1, 'Drama': 1, 'Mystery': 1})
```

Comment: Collections code worked. I further converted the dictonary to series/dataframe. Thank you. This is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

We can [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) and then use [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
out = (
    df['genre'].str.split('/')
        .explode()
        .value_counts()
        .rename_axis('Genre')
        .reset_index(name='count')
)
```

Or [`str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) and [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
out = (
    df['genre'].str.get_dummies('/').sum()
        .rename('Genre')
        .reset_index(name='count')
        .sort_values('count', ascending=False, ignore_index=True)
)
```

`out`:

```
       Genre  count
0  Animation      2
1     Sci-Fi      2
2     Action      1
3  Adventure      1
4      Drama      1
5    Mystery      1
```

Comment: Got an error. "'Series' object has no attribute 'explode'. trying to resolve it.

Comment: Series has had explode since `0.25.0` (July 18, 2019)